# Format Phone Number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a pandas dataframe and I am trying to format the phone numbers in such a way that I would like to add dashes between the numbers 306-877-9993 for each first three phone numbers. I would also like to remove the string "I don't have one" and the dummy phone number 999999999999. How can I do that? Thanks

```
  Last Name  First Name Phone number
0   Dupont      Marie   3068779993
1   Trey        Tom     16669858121
2   Johnson     Lily    (407)6579091
3   Parmentier  John    I don't have one
4   Predi       Pamela  999999999999
```

Edit: This is an Excel file that contains several phone numbers entered manually. I am trying to see if there's a way to format the phone numbers and clean the file. I have tried to strip the parenthesis with :  `df['Phone_number'] = df.Phone_number.str.strip('(')` But I am getting a bunch of NaN for some phone numbers.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please [edit] your question and post [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks, *all as formatted text in the question itself.* Do not post images of text.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This seems pretty broad. The format for data in your phone number column looks like it could be just about anything. What constraints are valid within this column? Have you tried writing any code yet? If so, where are you stuck? Thanks for clarifying

Comment: Hi @ggorlen - this is an Excel file with phone numbers entered manually, and am trying to see if there's a way I can clean this file with Python. In terms of code, I have tried to first strip the parenthesis df['Phone_number'] = df.Phone_number.str.strip('('), but it returns a lot of Nan and I am not sure why.

Comment: Hi @MattDMo I have updated my question. Hope this looks better! Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the update. If they're entered manually, it could be pretty much anything, so we'll need some kind of minimal but representative sample of input and expected output. It's not really possible to write a regex unless there's some specification for the format.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function [`clean_phone()`](https://sfu-db.github.io/dataprep/user_guide/clean/clean_phone.html) from the library [DataPrep](https://dataprep.ai/). Install it with `pip install dataprep`.

```py
>>> from dataprep.clean import clean_phone
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"Phone number": [3068779993, "16669858121", 
         "(407)6579091", "I don't have one", 999999999999]})
>>> clean_phone(df, "Phone number")
Phone Number Cleaning Report:                                                                                                 
        3 values cleaned (60.0%)
        2 values unable to be parsed (40.0%), set to NaN
Result contains 3 (60.0%) values in the correct format and 2 null values (40.0%)
       Phone number Phone number_clean
0        3068779993       306-877-9993
1       16669858121       666-985-8121
2      (407)6579091       407-657-9091
3  I don't have one                NaN
4      999999999999                NaN
```